# CSS Flexbox: align flex item with different width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align some flex items with different widths. I can not hit some elements.
https://jsfiddle.net/sistel/m1vu9exf/2/

I cannot align the texts and colored squares as shown in this figure http://www.farmacom.it/baseball.jpg

```
.flex-container-4 {
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: Black;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position:relative;
}

.flex-container-4 > div {
  background-color: BLACK;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: I have a small problem. I should separate the two flex-containers, in order to have the numbers in one container and the buttons in another. In this way the contents of the second do not align with the first. Is there a way to make the two containers the same width? This is my JS Fiiddle Link: jsfiddle.net/sistel/m1vu9exf/7 Thank you! –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-written your code using flex css and removed some unwanted styles. Hope this helps your problem

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="roman-numeric">I</div>
      <div class="roman-numeric">II</div>
      <div class="roman-numeric">III</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="text">BALL</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="seperator"></div>

  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="roman-numeric">IV</div>
      <div class="roman-numeric">V</div>
      <div class="roman-numeric">VI</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="text">STRIKE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="seperator"></div>

  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="roman-numeric">VII</div>
      <div class="roman-numeric">VIII</div>
      <div class="roman-numeric">IX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
      <div class="number">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="text">OUT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="orange"></div>
      <div class="orange"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: Black;
  justify-content: start;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-row>.number {
  background-color: #444;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: yellow;
}

.flex-row>.roman-numeric {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.flex-row>.text {
  background-color: BLACK;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.seperator {
  background: #a5a2a2;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/2ymefx81/

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution is perfect!

Comment: I have a small problem. I should separate the two flex-containers, in order to have the numbers in one container and the buttons in another.
In this way the contents of the second do not align with the first.
Is there a way to make the two containers the same width?

This is my JS Fiiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/sistel/m1vu9exf/7/

Thank you!

Comment: Easiest way would be to give the columns a width. This is another fiddle with your code. Hope it helps. https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/g7qtub9L/

Comment: You're right, it solves my problem. Last thing. Why don't I see the number in the last column centered?

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sistel/vkw81tgr/4/

Comment: What number are you talking about?

Comment: The number 10 and 20

Comment: Try adding a width to that column only. Should work out

Comment: I did it but nothing changes
JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/sistel/vkw81tgr/12/

Comment: Try this. I have added another class with a width for the column https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/ds3qn2k5/

Comment: Thank you, you are always so kind.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you created rows and cells from these rows doesn't know about other rows' dimensions - this is why in the last part, "VIII" takes more width than other elements.

One solution is to create columns instead of rows, because in this way, flex container will be of the width of the widest element.

Answer (score 0):

To get exact result you need to change your bit of html structure. If not i have created similar pattern using your current code. please check this:

[`Baseball Flex`](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/EzWrpK)

Comment: you can use these divs as outer container and out your content inside these as needed.